# adding characters from text file into an array

Tags: c, arrays

I am new to C and am trying to complete an assignment.  The program should take a file name as an command line argument, then print the file contents.  My program prints jumbled up text instead of the actual text in file.

I have searched all over the Internet for examples/answers to my problem and remain stuck!

What am I doing wrong?.  If it can be helped, please modify my code instead of writing new code so that I will have an easier time understanding.

```
int main()
{
    char fileName[20];
    int *buffer;
    int size;

    // ask for file name and take input.
    printf("Enter file name: ");            
    scanf("%s", fileName);

    // open file in read mode.
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen(fileName, "r");          

    // If no file, show error.
    if(fp == NULL)                  
    {
        printf("Error: Can't open file.\n");        
        return 1;
    }

    // count characters in file with fseek and put into size, then move the
    // position of the file back to the beginning.
    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
    size = ftell(fp);
    rewind(fp);

    // allocate buffer and read file into buffer.
    buffer = malloc(size+1);
    fread(buffer, 1, size, fp);

    // close the file.
    fclose(fp);

    // for loop reading array one character at a time.
    for(int x = 0; x < size; x++)
    {               
        printf("%c", buffer[x]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Always be wary of buffer overflows. A 20 character buffer is crazy tiny. If you're having a malfunction with compiled code, *open your debugger*.

Comment: `int *buffer` -> `char *buffer`

Comment: `x < size` : Use return value of `fread` instead of `size`. The number of actually read characters may be different.

Answer (score 2):

You are using the wrong datatype for reading in characters, i.e. you use `int *buffer`, but you should use `char *buffer`.

When using `int *buffer`, an access like `printf("%c",buffer[x])` will access your buffer as an array of integers; an integer is probably of size `4`, such that `buffer[1]` addresses the 4th byte in the buffer, `buffer[2]` the 8th and so forth... Hence, you will read out elements that are not contained in the file any more, actually exceeding array bounds (leading to garbage or something else).